# Return Different Decended Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, mocking, tdd

Background:
Trying to create mock data for a project using Entity Framework.

I think I need to return closed graphs of objects ( unless there is a better way of doing this):

There are 3 classes all derived from EntityBase, i.e.

```
class TA : EntityBase
class TB : EntityBase
class TC : EntityBase
```

TA has two virtual properties:

```
public virtual TB B { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<TC> C { get; set; }
```

TB has

```
public virtual ICollection<TA> A { get; set; }
```

TC has

```
public virtual TA A { get; set; }
```

In some places I need an instantiated object of TA or TB or TC.

Once I have fully handcrafted an instance of TA to be returned with all the properties of B and C filled in manually, instead of having 3 copies of the same  function to return A or B or C, is there a way to just have one copy of the method that instantiates an instance of A, but also returns B or C.

Something Like

`Get<A>()` , or `Get<B>()` or `Get<C>()`

of course all this might be not needed if there are simpler more standard ways of mocking Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off just creating three methods.

To do this with one method, you need to return an object of type `EntityBase`, since they all inherit from that.

```
public EntityBase MyMethod() {
    //return TA or TB or TC
}
```

But, you may have other types that inherit from `EntityBase` too, so it's technically possible to return a different type.

If you need to prevent that, you can make another type that inherits from `EntityBase` and then have your three classes (and only those three classes) inherit from that.

```
class MyEntityBase : EntityBase
class TA : MyEntityBase
class TB : MyEntityBase
class TC : MyEntityBase

public MyEntityBase MyMethod() {
    //return TA or TB or TC
}
```

But whether you do or don't do that, you still should verify which type gets returned and act accordingly.

```
var result = MyMethod()
if (result is TA myTA) {
    //do something with myTA
}
```

Of course, you can forego all that testing and assume you get the right value back, which very well may work..... but it's asking for something to break in the future :)